# MySQLでフィールド合計が0の場合のみ、その列を削除したい

Tags: mysql, sql

テーブルに複数列があり、合計が1以上の列だけテーブルに残したいです。
また、残った列は列名を変えたいのですが、コードが分からず苦戦しております。

ストアドプロシージャ？を使う必要があるのか？まで行きついたのですが八方ふさがりになってしまいました。

#### 環境

OS：Win10 64bit
MySQL：mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.33, for Win32 (AMD64)
実行環境：コマンドプロンプト

#### 現行のtbl

```
user, price, a, i, u, e, o, ka, ki, ku
yamada, 600, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0
tanaka, 780, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
kato,   500, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0
```

#### 期待する処理

1. user列とprice列を除くaからkuまでの列の合計をチェックする
2. 列合計が0の場合、列ごと削除
3. 列合計が0より大きい場合、列名を変える（a列なら「あ」、i列なら「い」のように）

※2,3ともに、人間が目で見て `ALTER TABLE tbl DROP/RENAME COLUMN～` で削除/列名変更するのではなく、クエリ文で対応したい

#### 処理後の[after_tbl]イメージ

```
user, price, あ, い, う, え, お
yamada, 600, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
tanaka, 780, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
kato,   500, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1
```

Comment: 保守機能とか想定されています？システム稼働中の処理であまりDMLをたたかないほうがいいと考えているので。。。どれぐらいの頻度で何を変えるのか。DDLで実現できないのか、参考までおしえてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。説明不足ですみません。
処理環境としては（本番の基幹ではなく）ローカルでの作業となり、レポートを作るためです。
頻度は1回なのですが、列名変更・削除は手作業ではないやり方を探しております。
また上記背景のため、保守やシステム稼働への影響は度外視しています。

Comment: 列名を変えてしまうと既存のクエリが全て無意味になってしまい、データベースとしての存在価値がなくなります。テーブル変更はできる／できないではなく、やるべきでない行為です。

Comment: そうですね、ただ、テーブル構造を変えるというよりレポート用にみやすく出力するためという位置づけです。列名変更後のテーブルを用いてDBとして存在させることは考えておりません。

Comment: 個人的な意見ですが、SQLの勉強のためといいますが、非常に特殊な使い方のような気もします。あまり有用に使える場面もなさそうです。ストアドプロシージャを学びたいのであれば、厳密な運用を求めるような決済による通貨移動や在庫管理などを事例にしたほうがいいような気もします。

Comment: ご回答いただいたみなさまありがとうございます。ご意見や対応コストを考慮し、手動での処理とすることとしました。
要件によりフィットする別の機会でストアドプロシージャも勉強していきたいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

ストアドプロシージャにて実現可能でしょうが、一般のプログラミング言語と比べると構文がやや特殊で色々と面倒なので、一度切りの作業であれば私ならExcelやGoogleスプレッドシートで対応してしまいます。

サンプルを用意してみました。
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IazXHy5Up91VaqoLLoS4MOdeRqLpor53a5VaEDql_L4/edit?usp=sharing
※閲覧のみ可にしております

データをCSV等にエクスポートして、スプレッドシートに貼り付け、リネーム後のカラム名を手動で入力。
あとはSUM関数とIF文で実行したいALTER文を出力。

最後に出来上がったALTER文の行をコピーして流すだけです。

Comment: わざわざスプレッドシート準備・公開いただき恐縮です。ありがとうございます。
そうですよね、実務的には最もこの方法が有用ですよね。。
ただ頻度は1回なのですが、SQLの勉強のためにMySQLのみで完結できる方法を模索しています。
その場合、やはりストアドプロシージャになるのでしょうか。。（面倒くさくてすみません…）